# Get list of what special characters and how many times in oracle column

Tags: sql, oracle, count, special-characters

I'm searching for a way to get a list of special characters and how many times they appear in my column.  I've tried using using regexp_count which works, but I'm not sure how to extend it to make it work for all special characters in one query.

For example for syntax = 'x=y*100' with the following query I get

```
select *
  from (
         select regexp_count(syntax, '\*') as charCnt, syntax
           from tblTemp
       ) 
     where charCnt > 0
```

charCnt=1 and syntax='x=y*100'.

Which is correct but I want to be able to get back

```
specChar Cnt

\*       1
=        1
etc..
```

Comment: could you use [![:alnum:]] as in not alpha numeric this is using the character classes.

Comment: I tried that and it returns rows with special characters but the count doesn't seem right.    I have another case like this syntax = '(test > 0) and (test2 <1)'  I need to have  2='('    2=')'     1='>'    1='<'

Comment: sorry it is ^ not !  so   select regexp_count('x=y*100', '[^[:alnum:]]') as charCnt from dual gives you a value of 2.

Comment: the special character classes are alnum, alpha, blank (which are spaces and tabs), cntrl (nonprinting or control characters), digit, graph(graphical characters), print (printable characters), punct (punctuation characters), space (whitespace characters space and form feed and newline etc.), upper and xdigit (hexadecimal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  id INT,
  value NVARCHAR2(200)
);

INSERT INTO table_name
  SELECT 1, N'y=20x+3'          FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, N'***^%$%$%*&*.&\?' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, UNISTR('\00B5\00B6\00B5')  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, N'!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()'
            || N'!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()'
            || N'!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()'
            || N'!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()!"£$%^&*()' FROM DUAL;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE CHAR_LIST IS TABLE OF CHAR(1 CHAR);
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT  t.id,
        --MAX( t.value ) AS value,
        CAST( c.COLUMN_VALUE AS CHAR(1 CHAR) ) AS character,
        COUNT(1) AS frequency
FROM    table_name t,
        TABLE(
          CAST(
            MULTISET(
              SELECT SUBSTR( t.value, LEVEL, 1 )
              FROM   DUAL
              WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR( t.value, LEVEL, 1 ), '[^a-zA-Z0-9]' )
              CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH( t.value )
            ) AS CHAR_LIST
          )
        ) c
GROUP BY t.id, c.COLUMN_VALUE
ORDER BY id, character;
```

**Output**:

```
        ID CHARACTER  FREQUENCY
---------- --------- ----------
         1 +                  1 
         1 =                  1 
         2 $                  2 
         2 %                  3 
         2 &                  2 
         2 *                  5 
         2 .                  1 
         2 ?                  1 
         2 \                  1 
         2 ^                  1 
         3 µ                  2 
         3 ¶                  1 
         4 !                 20 
         4 "                 20 
         4 $                 20 
         4 %                 20 
         4 &                 20 
         4 (                 20 
         4 )                 20 
         4 *                 20 
         4 ^                 20 
         4 £                 20
```

Comment: Thank you MT0.  I'm going to add an outside query to sum out the frequency so I get a distinct list of characters with their counts.

Comment: I'm getting this error and I'm not sure which cast is causing it?  It displays many rows of data then I get the error.         SQL Error: ORA-25137: Data value out of range
25137. 00000 -  "Data value out of range"
*Cause:    Value from cast operand is larger than cast target size.
*Action:   Increase size of cast target.

Comment: @JerryWarra Updated - changed `CAST( .. AS CAST(1) )` to `CAST( .. AS CAST(1 CHAR) )` and changed `SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST` to a UDT. I've not been able to replicate your issue but I'm hoping that one or both of those will fix your issue. If it doesn't then you might need to post a description of your table and a sample of your data.

Comment: Your updated version worked perfectly.  Thank you so much